# RHEL - SSH login with root but no password

Tags: key, root, sshd

I am struggling hard with enabling root ssh login with key authentication, after hours I discovered that I cannot login using key when starting sshd with command

```
service sshd start
```

but when I start /usr/sbin/sshd either alone or with default config file

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh.sshd_config
```

I am able to login with public key without problems. Does anyone have idea why? My settings:

```
root@localhost:/etc/ssh# egrep -v -e ^# -e ^$ sshd_config 
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PermitRootLogin yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysCommand none
AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding yes
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

PAM module:

```
root@localhost:/etc/pam.d# cat sshd
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required pam_sepermit.so
auth       include      password-auth
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
```

I am using DSA keys and here is verbose output:

```
debug1: Host 'rhel' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/cyki/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug2: bits set: 508/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/cyki/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0),
debug2: key: /Users/cyki/.ssh/id_dsa (0x7fbac34155a0),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/cyki/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/cyki/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /Users/cyki/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: in the second instance you are starting `sshd` as root yes? when you run as a service is it running as root? Do the files have the necessary permissions?

Comment: Yep I am working only under root user so in both cases sshd is launched under root, I also tested to be sure. Additionally I have noticed that when I set "UsePAM no" I am not able to log in at all even with password. Might be that PAM is somehow coded into sshd and I have to use it?